# Using multiple criteria for IF/THEN function

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, conditional, if

I am trying to display relevant content to users of a certain type (pro or commercial), but I do have some users that are marked as both. in that case i am using another field (customer type) to determine the content they should receive. I get an error in testing "Error 1: Script IF Statement Invalid
An error occurred when attempting to resolve a script expression. See inner exception for detail. Script Expression: ("Commercial"

```
%%[IF @PRO == TRUE AND @COMM == TRUE AND @CustomerType == ("Commercial" OR 
"Architect" OR "Builder") THEN]%%
 <--commercial content-->

[ELSEIF @PRO == TRUE AND @COMM == TRUE AND @CustomerType == ("Professional" 
OR "Consumer" OR "Contractor") THEN]%%
<--Pro content-->

%%[ELSE]%%
<--default content-->

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark-symbol on the left of it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You cannot check for multiple strings in a single variable like you did. You need to split the expression. Additionally you are missing two percent-signs for the elseif-part.

So the following part:

```vb
@CustomerType == ("Commercial" OR "Architect" OR "Builder")
```

is changed to this:

```vb
(@CustomerType == "Commercial" OR @CustomerType == "Architect" OR @CustomerType == "Builder")
```

This also needs to be done for the expression in the elseif. So this would be the complete code snippet:

```vb
%%[IF @PRO == TRUE AND @COMM == TRUE AND (@CustomerType == "Commercial" OR @CustomerType == "Architect" OR @CustomerType == "Builder") THEN]%%
    <--commercial content-->
%%[ELSEIF @PRO == TRUE AND @COMM == TRUE AND (@CustomerType == "Professional" OR @CustomerType == "Consumer" OR @CustomerType == "Contractor") THEN]%%
    <--Pro content-->
%%[ELSE]%%
    <--default content-->
%%[ENDIF]%%
```

**Helpful resources:**

- [Get Started with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/getStarted-AMPscript.htm)
- [AMPscript Language Elements](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/languageElements.htm)